# The function is not being called by browser when you reload the page? What is wrong?

Tags: javascript

Why is the function is not being called? What is wrong?

```
var database = [{username: "Sean", password: 1995}];
var newsFeed = [{username: "Tanya", timeline: "She says it very cool"}, {username: "Misha", timeline: "Misha is working at sphere of railways"}];

var askUsernameByPrompt = prompt("What is your username");
var askPasswordByPrompt = prompt("What is your password");


function signIn(user, pass){
    if(user ==== database[0].username && pass === database[0].password) {console.log(newsFeed);}
    else{alert("Sorry, username or password!");}
}
signIn(askUsernameByPrompt, askPasswordByPrompt);
```

Comment: Can you give us a little context? Dumping some code saying "it's not being called" doesn't give us nearly enough insight to the problem you're encountering. First thing's first: check your Javascript console, there is a glaring syntax error.

Comment: If that's your exact code, at a glance there's at least one syntax error (`user ==== database` has too many ='s).  If that's not the problem, can you add some more information as to what's actually happening?

Comment: Right, there was a syntax error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, Its running

```
var database = [{username: "Sean", password: 1995}];
var newsFeed = [{username: "Tanya", timeline: "She says it very cool"}, {username: "Misha", timeline: "Misha is working at sphere of railways"}];

var askUsernameByPrompt = prompt("What is your username");
var askPasswordByPrompt = prompt("What is your password");


function signIn(user, pass){
    if(user === database[0].username && pass === database[0].password) {console.log(newsFeed);}
    else{alert("Sorry, username or password!");}
}
signIn(askUsernameByPrompt, askPasswordByPrompt);
```

You just made a little mistake in if condition, for strict equality comparison in JavaScript, we write `===` that checks for both **type** and **content** but you mistakenly typed `====`  which is wrong syntax. For more information on comparison operator check its official documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Comment: Wait, how did this get answered after it was put on hold?

Comment: @John Montgomery, I think the moment it was put on hold and when I submitted answer was exactly same point of time :)